# lmhost and testing websites locally

Tags: web, pyrocms

I have to manage a few websites. For testing I have a local (`localhost`) copy and an online copy.

The cms engine [http://Pyrocms.com](http://Pyrocms.net) has a multi-site manager and you enter a domain. In the browser you enter the domain name and it serves the website for the request site that is stored in a central database.

Online this works fine but locally it doesn't, I end up having to type

```
localhost/silo1/myclient1/
```

I would like to be able to type

```
myclient1.test
```

The first thing I thought of was **lmhost** file, but I releasise I cant map to the sub directories, just the IP addresses.

Below is what I tried to do in the host file in Windows7, it didnt work, it just directed me to `127.0.0.1`  when I entered `mywebsite2.test`.

**HOST FILE** - **AKA LMHOST**

```
File stored @ #C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
lmhost/host file
127.0.0.1                   mywebsite1.test
127.0.0.1/mywebsite2/       mywebsite2.test  **#I want to do something like this**
```

**Technologies:**

- OS: Windows7 Server: WAMP 2
- (Apache with Mod Rewrite on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the only way you are going to accomplish that is by...

Editing the HOSTS file (not LMHOSTS) to resolving your fake domain-name to the loopback address (127.0.0.1).

```
127.0.0.1 myclient1.test
127.0.0.1 myclient2.test
```

Then use an .htaccess file with mod_rewrite conditions and rules to match the host header (for each different website) and internally rewrite the request to the proper sub-folder/sub-url.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myclient1\.test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ http://localhost/silo1/myclient1/$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myclient2\.test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ http://localhost/silo2/myclient2/$1 [NC]
```

Or if you want to do a full redirect (instead of an internal redirect)...

```
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ http://localhost/silo1/myclient1/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: -I tried your solution and it worked too, Im giving you the credit, but see my solution as well.

Comment: @IEnumerable, my fault, the way I originally read it was that going through the "localhost" VH or URL was a requirement. Without that, using a separate VH for each domain-name will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edits to the HOST file.

```
127.0.0.1 myclient1.test
127.0.0.1 myclient2.test
```

In the httpd.conf file I added

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myclient1.test
   DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\silo1\myclient1\
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myclient2.test
   DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\silo1\myclient2\
</VirtualHost>
```